Filtering by a combination of parent and child fields in a unidirectional JPA relation
I have 2 entities in a unidirectional one-to-many relationship, but I want to query all child entities based on their own and their parent's details. Say for example I have Author (parent) and a list of Books (child) and I want to search for Books based on their title and the name of the Author. To make it simple, let's just say there's one-to-many author to books.
At the minute, I'm able to query books using author's name using a query a like this:
select a.books from Author a where name = :name

Just to reiterate, the relationship is unidirectional so there's no reference from Book to Author. How do I modify the query above to also filter by the book title?

Should just be “select b from Author a join a.books b where a.name = :name and b.title = :title”

Exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks! Didn't know how to express the join in this case and was tempted to just use a native query.
